# posting a text message in a listview android tutorial

Tags: android

I'm working on my first app which is basically a simple app containing a registration system and the ability to post a text message on a "feed" , "wall" page
I successfully did the registration system, now i only need to know how to get the text written in the "post something" box and place it on the feed page so everyone can see it.
This is the code:

I just did a text to add a text in a listview but the app is crashing before even opening

Main:

```
package com.example.ali.bla;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mainListView ;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Find the ListView resource.
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

        // Create and populate a List of planet names.
        String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
        ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            new Intent(MainActivity.this, post.class);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is post class where i want to extract text written by usrs and add it in the listview :

```
package com.example.ali.bla;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class post extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

these are the xml files:

main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainListView">
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and for the post:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.bla.post">


   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/post"
       android:hint="share with us !"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: please post ur crash logcat msg